# Issue with URL rewriting and parameter GET

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some problem to build my url rewrite. On my local server, working with `nginx`, everything is going well. But as soon as I try to make it working for `apache` with `htacces`, I kind of get crazy.

My urls are looking like this:

> http://example.com/controller/action/param1/value1/param2/value2

Following is the `htaccess` working for the previous case:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(images|css|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But in some case I have some extra parameter, for example for Facebook authentication:

> http://example.com/controller/action?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1382665465

This case is not working with the previous `htaccess`. Nothing is going in the GET variables. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `QSA` (Query String Append) flag in your rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(images|css|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

`QSA` flag makes sure to preserve an existing query string while adding new query parameters.